# How to launch new viewPager on reaching last page of current ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I am making a book reading application. Each chapter is an entry in drawer list. I have multiple view pagers, each corresponding to an item in drawer list. How to launch next view pager (next chapter) on reaching to end of previous one.

Comment: How to capture end of a viewPager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Post some code to understand the context.

But as a general solution,  we can add a page dynamically to viewpager while swiping, instead of adding a new viewpager.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be ugly but you can try changing the visibility of the `viewpager` when required.

When you finish the first viewpager i.e. `viewpager1`,set:

```
viewpager1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
viewpager2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

P.S.: Initially set all viewpagers `.setVisibility(View.GONE);` except the first one.